# Allow location access in Android WebView (compatible before and after 23)

Tags: android, webview, kotlin, geolocation

[Android + Kotlin] I can't get a simple Android webview app to access device location (Note: I'm using emulators). The webview works just fine except I never see a prompt to allow location and I'm never given location data. My manifest file includes the following:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

My activity class looks like this:

```
class WebViewActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    class ModifiedWebChromeClient: WebChromeClient() {
        override fun onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(origin: String?, callback: GeolocationPermissions.Callback?) {
            callback!!.invoke(origin, true, false);
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_blind_spot_web_view)

        val webView: WebView = findViewById(R.id.webView)
        val webSettings = webView.settings
        webSettings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        webSettings.setGeolocationEnabled(true)

        val client = ModifiedWebChromeClient()
        webView.webChromeClient = client

        webView.loadUrl("https://www.example.com")
    }
}
```

What else do I need to make this work? API level 23 and above give an error saying

```
Caught security exception while registering for location updates from the system. The application does not have sufficient geolocation permissions.
```

Below level 23 I don't see an error but I also don't see any location information. I'm not sure what to do here. I'd also appreciate an answer in Kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ASSISTED_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```